# Mostrar columnas R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quiero mostrar con R Studio el valor máximo de una columna. Bien esto, lo tengo hecho, lo que ahora no se como hacer para poder mostrar los valores de todas las columnas de esa fila.

Lo que tengo hecho es esto:

```
max(nombreArchivo$nombreColumna)
```

Esto me muestra el valor máximo de esa columna, y lo que quiero también es que se muestre los demás valores junto con el nombre de las columnas. He probado con esto y no funciona.

```
max(nombreArchivo$nombreColumna[c("columna1","columna2")])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R permite indexar o acceder a las matrices, data.frames y otro objetos, mediante vectores lógicos, por lo que puedes simplemente recuperar aquellas filas dónde `nombreArchivo$nombreColumna == max(nombreArchivo$nombreColumna)`, algo así:

```
nombreArchivo[nombreArchivo$nombreColumna == max(nombreArchivo$nombreColumna), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera de lograrlo es  con la funciona `which.max` la cual devuelve el indice del valor máximo de un vector numérico

```
nombreArchivo[which.max(nombreArchivo$nombreColumna), ]
```